# Can't generate apk: zipalign.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, apk

I try to generate apk for an app.

Here is the **error** i got:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:MyApp:assembleRelease]
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19-1' (Expected 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19')
:MyApp:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:checkReleaseManifest
:MyApp:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:compileLint
:MyAppEssentialsLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:checkReleaseManifest
:MyAppEssentialsLib:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk460Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGithubAfollestadMaterialDialogsCore0856Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGithubJkwiecienEasyImage109Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareDeHdodenhofCircleimageview200Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareMeZhanghaiAndroidMaterialprogressbarLibrary114Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:MyAppEssentialsLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:MyAppEssentialsLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk460Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGithubAfollestadMaterialDialogsCore0856Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGithubJkwiecienEasyImage109Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareDeHdodenhofCircleimageview200Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareMeZhanghaiAndroidMaterialprogressbarLibrary114Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareReleaseDependencies
:MyApp:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:processReleaseGoogleServices
:MyApp:generateReleaseResources
:MyApp:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:lintVitalRelease
:MyApp:prePackageMarkerForRelease
:MyApp:transformClassesWithDexForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:validateExternalOverrideSigning
:MyApp:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:zipalignRelease
Unable to open 'C:\Users\MyApp-release.apk' as zip archive
Error:Execution failed for task ':MyApp:zipalignRelease'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I dont't get it whats the **cause**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clean the project and restart Android Studio and regenerate the `APK` and this time change your `APK`path to desktop when generating .

it will most probably solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The destination path `C:\Users\MyApp-release.apk` seems wrong.

It should be something like `C:\Users\MyUser\MyApp-release.apk`.